# ¿Cómo solucionar java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared?

Tags: java

Intente con el siguiente código:

**main**

```
import interfaz.ventanaJf;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        new ventanaJf();
    }
}
```

**ventanaJf**

```
package interfaz;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ventanaJf{

    private JPanel panelDatos,panelSaldo;
    private JLabel texto1,texto2;
    private JFrame frame;

    public void construyePanelDatos(){

        panelDatos = new JPanel();
        texto1 = new JLabel("Datos");
        panelDatos.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelDatos, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        panelDatos.add(texto1);
    }

    public void construyePanelSaldo(){

        panelSaldo = new JPanel();
        texto2 = new JLabel("Saldo");
        panelSaldo.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelSaldo, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        panelSaldo.add(texto2);

    }

    public void construyeVentana(){

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        frame.add(panelDatos);
        frame.add(panelSaldo);

        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//finaliza el programa cuando se da click en la X
        frame.setSize(270,180);//configurando tamaño de la ventana
        frame.setVisible(true);//configurando visualización de la ventana
        frame.setResizable(false);//para configurar si se redimensiona la ventana
        frame.setLocation((int)((d.width)/2-560),d.height/2-360);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public ventanaJf(){
        construyePanelDatos();
        construyePanelSaldo();
        construyeVentana();
    }
}
```

pero al ejecutar me sale el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.checkContainer(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.invalidateLayout(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at interfaz.ventanaJf.construyeVentana(ventanaJf.java:37)
at interfaz.ventanaJf.<init>(ventanaJf.java:57)
at main.main(main.java:7)
```

**Pregunta**

Comenté en el código donde se genera el error, pero no pude solucionarlo. ¿Qué es lo que está incorrecto o cómo se solucionaría?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow Julian. La verdad es que es un error que se las trae, hasta una experta en java podría caer en ese error. Te sugiero que cambies el título por uno que entre más al grano de lo que tratas en la pregunta como por ejemplo : ¿Cómo solucionar java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared? , puedes hacerlo pulsando en "editar" justo al final de tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias Jose lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima, realmente soy muy nuevo en todo esto, y agradezco toda la ayuda y consejos que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que un `BorderLayout` debe ser utilizado en el mismo contenedor que el pasado como parámetro al constructor de `BorderLayout`.

Por tanto la siguiente línea estaría mal, pues usamos `frame.getContentPane()` y `frame`, que son diferentes :

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

Y la siguiente estaría bien, pues usamos `frame.getContentPane()` y `frame.getContentPane()` que son el mismo (y poniendo esta línea el programa de la pregunta hace lo que de el se espera) :

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

Entonces, ¿por qué la línea del autor de la pregunta está mal? Está usando `frame` y `frame`, que debieran ser iguales :

```
frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

El motivo es que `JFrame` es un [`RootPaneContainer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RootPaneContainer.html) en el que :

> For conveniance JFrame, JDialog, JWindow, JApplet and JInternalFrame,
>   by default, forward, by default, all calls to the add, remove and
>   setLayout methods, to the contentPane.

Que traducido es :

> Por comodidad JFrame, JDialog, JWindow, JApplet y JInternalFrame,  por defecto, redirigen, por defecto, todas las llamadas a los métodos add, remove, y setLayout, al contentPane

Es decir, cuando ejecutas `frame.setLayout` en realidad se está ejecutando `frame.getContentPane().setLayout`

Comment: He comprobado que al substituir la línea que identifico como errónea por la que propongo como correcta el programa sí funciona. No alcanzo a imaginar qué motivo legítimo puede haber para el -1.

Answer (score 1):

Yo, por otra parte, cambié el tipo de layout que usaste por el flowLayout (También podrías usar el gridBagLayout).

`frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`

Y es importante que le indiques a la clase que tipo de elemento será. Por ejemplo, si quieres que tu ventana se comporte como un JFrame, es necesario que le agregues a la clase un extends JFrame.
Esto lo haces al inicio de la misma:

```
public class ventanaJf extends JFrame{
//Todo tu codigo...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Podrías cambiar la siguiente línea

```
frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

por

```
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

Pues el problema es el boxLayout si ahora quieres ajustarlo sería algo como

```
public void construyeVentana(){

        frame = new JFrame();

        Box verticalBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        verticalBox.add(panelSaldo);
        verticalBox.add(panelDatos);
        frame.getContentPane().add(verticalBox, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);       
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//finaliza el programa cuando se da click en la X
        frame.setSize(270,180);//configurando tamaño de la ventana
        frame.setVisible(true);//configurando visualización de la ventana
        frame.setResizable(false);//para configurar si se redimensiona la ventana
        frame.setLocation((int)((d.width)/2-560),d.height/2-360);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Los paneles se agregan al Box
más información en:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

Comment: Usando un GridLayout el programa funciona, en efecto. Pero ten en cuenta que el problema no es el BoxLayout; es posible hacer funcionar el programa con BoxLayout con cambios mínimos.